# Shell script Calling multiple shell scripts that use STDIN via SSH

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, nested

So I have a process that moves and renames files using multiple scripts.  I want to have a script that runs all of these scripts.  Firstly I SSH into my server then cd to the appropriate directory then run the script.  Looks like this.

```
ssh me@myserver.com<EOF
cd ../../path/to/files/
sh script1.sh
EOF
```

This script1.sh then asks for a directory name for which to run the script and uses it in it's path.  Once this script is complete I have another script I'd like to run on the same server, so I would modify my calling script to look like this.

```
ssh me@myserver.com<EOF
cd ../../path/to/files/
sh script1.sh
cd ../../diff/directory
sh script2.sh
EOF
```

This doesn't work...  I guess there's an issue with STDIN using SSH in a nested script?  Hope someone knows of an easy fix without changing too much.

Comment: A heredoc uses `<<EOF` -- using a single angle bracket reads from the **file** named "EOF"

Comment: When script1 asks for a directory name, do you want this to be interactive or automated?

Comment: Interactive.  Different directory name daily.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you take user's input and echo back in remote shell using ssh:

```
ssh -t user@myhost "read -p \"enter val: \" a && echo \"Entered val is: \$a\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider what can be done continuing on with the `here` document approach.

> This script1.sh then asks for a directory name. ...I guess there's an issue with STDIN

Yes.  Have a look at your script:

```
ssh me@myserver.com <<EOF
cd ../../path/to/files/
sh script1.sh
cd ../../diff/directory
sh script2.sh
EOF
```

When `script1.sh` runs, its `stdin` is not from your terminal; it is from the `here` document.  The following demonstrates this:

```
$ mydir="some/path/" ; ssh home <<EOF
date
read var
$mydir
echo "I got var=\$var"
EOF
```

This produces the output:

```
Fri Mar 21 14:34:03 PDT 2014
I got var=some/path/
```

What happened is that the `read` statement asked `stdin` for another line.  It got the next line of the `here` document.

If you want `script1.sh` to ask for a path on `stdin`, you need to supply that path in the next line of your `here` script.

P.S. Complications like this are one reason are why *nix programmers usually prefer to put parameters as arguments on the command line rather than asking for them as input.